Autocorrelation of a vector series (3)
I used System.Linq.Count(). However, I found that function slow.
So, I wrote this function in C# 4.7.0.
        public static int CountElements(IEnumerable<Vec3> vectorList)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var enumerator = vectorList.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) count++; // Count elements manually
            return count;
        }

This function takes several seconds to return in the case of a few hundred thousand data points.
How can I make it lightling fast?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyLib
{
    public static class TimeSeriesAnalysis
    {
        public static int CountElements(IEnumerable<Vec3> vectorList)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var enumerator = vectorList.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) count++; // Count elements manually
            return count;
        }

        public static double AutoCorr(int lag, IEnumerable<Vec3> vectorList)
        {
            int n = CountElements(vectorList);
            if (n == 0 || lag >= n || lag < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Lag must be between 0 and {n - 1}, and the list cannot be empty.");

            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - lag; i++)
            {
                var enumerator = vectorList.GetEnumerator();
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) enumerator.MoveNext();
                var vecA = enumerator.Current;

                enumerator = vectorList.GetEnumerator();
                for (int j = 0; j <= i + lag; j++) enumerator.MoveNext();
                var vecB = enumerator.Current;

                sum += vecA.Dot(vecB);
            }

            return sum / (n - lag);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<double> GetTValues(int maxLag, int vectorCount)
        {
            int validMaxLag = Math.Min(maxLag, vectorCount - 1); // Ensure maxLag does not exceed n-1
            for (int lag = 0; lag <= validMaxLag; lag++)
            {
                yield return lag;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<double> GetCResults(IEnumerable<Vec3> vectorList, int maxLag, double c0)
        {
            for (int lag = 0; lag <= maxLag; lag++)
            {
                double cValue = 0;
                try
                {
                    cValue = AutoCorr(lag, vectorList);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    yield break; // Exit the loop if an invalid lag is encountered
                }
                yield return cValue / c0; // Normalization is done here
            }
        }

        public static PairReturn<double> GetAutoCorrelationPoints(IEnumerable<Vec3> vectors, int maxLag)
        {
            int vectorCount = CountElements(vectors);

            double c0 = AutoCorr(0, vectors); // This is the normalization factor
            Console.WriteLine($"Normalization factor: {c0}");

            return new PairReturn<double>(GetTValues(maxLag, vectorCount), GetCResults(vectors, maxLag, c0));
        }
    }
}


if Count() is slow, then you're doing something wrong. Actually, Count() does not count all IEnumerable types manually, instead, it tests it with  ICollection first, if success, then it returns the count immediately. If the  IEnumerable cannot be casted to ICollection then, it would enumerate over the elements and return the count. The enumeration is also optimized for large collections as well.
So, your CountElments would be unnecessary, and might even hurt your code performance. Using Count() with large collections might hurt your performance, as sometimes you don't need to count nor allocating memory, you just need to read as fast as possible.
To overcome this, you can use ICollection instead of IEnumerable and then use .Count property. It's a base interface for countable collections such as Array and List.
Another issue that I see is using static class for a collection that needs to be processed once. If you use a static class, then you're going to re-calculate the collection on every exposed method like AutoCorr, GetCResults and GetAutoCorrelationPoints. So, it would process the collection 3 times.
What you can do is to have an instance where you can pass the collection into the constructor, prepare it, and count it once then reuse it globally. Then, you can reuse that instance with a single vectorList. each vectorList will have its own class.
public sealed class TimeSeriesAnalysis
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Vec3> _source; 
    private int _count;
    
    public TimeSeriesAnalysis(IEnumerable<Vec3> vectorList)
    {
        _source = vectorList;
        _count  = vectorList.Count();
    }
    
    public double AutoCorr(int lag)
    {
        int n = _count;
        
        if (n == 0 || lag >= n || lag < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Lag must be between 0 and {n - 1}, and the list cannot be empty.");

        double sum = 0;
        
        int targetIndex = n - lag;

        for (int i = 0; i < targetIndex; i++)
        {
            var vecA = _source.Skip(i).Take(1).First();

            var vecB = _source.Skip(i+lag).Take(1).First();
        
            sum += vecA.Dot(vecB);
        }

        return sum / (n - lag);
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<double> GetCResults(int maxLag, double c0)
    {
        for (int lag = 0; lag <= maxLag; lag++)
        {
            double cValue = 0;
            
            try
            {
                cValue = AutoCorr(lag);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                yield break; // Exit the loop if an invalid lag is encountered
            }
            
            yield return cValue / c0; // Normalization is done here
        }
    }
    
    public PairReturn<double> GetAutoCorrelationPoints(int maxLag)
    {
        int vectorCount = _count;

        double c0 = AutoCorr(0); // This is the normalization factor
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Normalization factor: {c0}");
        
        int validMaxLag = Math.Min(maxLag, _count - 1); // Ensure maxLag does not exceed n-1
        
        var values = Enumerable.Range(0, validMaxLag + 1).Select(lag => (double)lag);

        return new PairReturn<double>(values, GetCResults(maxLag, c0));
    }
    
}

